# Can composite states contain do actions?

Tags: uml, statechart

I know that composite states are composed of internal states which show how the state behaves.  Can you also have a do action when the state is active? this is like showing parallel behavior in the state and seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the [UML Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/): yes, composite states may also contain do actions.